# How can I find the exact name of a button on an app for automated clicking?

Tags: c++, winapi, button

[image: recorder app]

I am trying to find the name of a button on an app that I am trying to make a program click automatically for me. How can I confirm the exact name of the button?

I tried hovering over the button and it says "Record" but my code below will not obtain the proper ID in the code below:

```
BOOL CALLBACK GetButtonHandle(HWND handle, LPARAM)
{
    char label[100];
    int size = GetWindowTextA(handle, label, sizeof(label));
    if (strcmp(label, "Record") == 0) // your button name
    {
        buttonHandle = handle;
        cout << "button id is: " << handle << endl; // All I get is 00000000
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    bool open = true;
    HWND windowHandle = FindWindowA(NULL, "EaseUSMainWindow");

    if (windowHandle == NULL)
    {
        cout << "app isn't open." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "app is open :) " << endl;
        cout << "ID is: " << windowHandle << endl;
        SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
        BOOL ret = EnumChildWindows(windowHandle, GetButtonHandle, 0); //find the button
        cout << buttonHandle << endl;
        if (buttonHandle != 0)
        {
            LRESULT res = SendMessage(buttonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached a picture of the UI of the external program

Comment: You might be looking for a tool called [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment), which is included with Visual Studio. It lets you see all kinds of information for a specific window.

Comment: Since this is a custom rendered UI it's reasonable to assume that there aren't any `HWND`s backing the controls. Regardless, the go to solution to automate UIs should be [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).  Use the [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to see what your UI looks like to an automation client.

Comment: And you can also use UI Automation to iterate children. See [How to Walk the UI Automation Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-walk-uiautomation-tree) and [the document example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessiblechildren#examples).